# Chord length Distribution Function (CDF) in an inhomogeneous medium

Tags: probability-distributions, random-graphs, tomography

Presumably this is a classic problem, but I would need an informed (but nevertheless elementary) answer or citation to start:

Assume a collection of hard, impenetrable 3-spheres (phase B), randomly distributed in a homogeneous medium (phase A). The distribution function of the radii R of the spheres is denoted p(R) and is not known.

A random plane P cuts through phase A and intersects phase B in a set of cuts, or 2-speres of different radii r, their distribution function q(r) being known.

Question: is it possible to reconstruct p(R) starting from the q(r) determined on a single plane?

Comment: Since you tagged this "tomography", I suspect that you're working in three dimensions. In that case, you mean "$2$-spheres" where you write "$3$-spheres" and "$1$-spheres" where you write "$2$-spheres" (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)). (You could of course also just call them "spheres" and "circles", respectively.)

Comment: You don't say anything about the spatial distribution of the spheres. If there's long-range order in the system, the distribution of the chord lengths may be concentrated around some value that depends on the plane you choose. I suspect that you're not interested in that sort of thing, but then it's unclear how the fact that the spheres are impenetrable is relevant to the question. Aren't you just interested in how spheres with independently uniformly distributed centres are cut by an arbitrary plane?

Comment: Yes, phases A and B are both in three dimensions. There is no long range order between the spheres, and no interaction which could cause ordering. The condition of rigidity and impenetrability is just to make sure we are always dealing with distinct, undeformed spheres (keeps the problem "simple") but has otherwise no dynamical meaning. Imagine randomly distributed nuclei of given concentration (Nr/cm^3), which subsequently start to grow but will stop when contact with neighbor is made. A snapshot of this medium during growth is a good description of the system.

Comment: Use of tag "tomography": I checked the link you indicated and I find this problem similar to the tomographic one, albeit in a statistical sense. The size of 3D objects or more precisely, their size distribution, is to be inferred from measurements made on a two dimensional section. There the spheres appear as discs, and the statistics of the disc diameters can be made from a two dimensional picture of the section. There could be enough redundancy to reconstruct the 3D (statistical) properties from a 2D cut through the containing medium, with all cuts being statistically equivalent.